# org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException while deserialising String

Tags: java, deserialization, objectmapper, fasterxml

I have the following string in a resource file and I am trying to deserialise to Map using ObjectMapper

> { 13714974: { get-url: "https://example.com/get", post-url:
>   "https://example.com/post" }, 13743772: { get-url:
>   "https://example.com/get", post-url: "https://example.com/post" }

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> cmMappings = mapper.readValue(content, Map.class);
```

When I use codehaus jackson ObjectMapper and try to deserialise it, I get the exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7cdbc5d3; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase._constructError(JsonParserBase.java:651)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase._reportError(JsonParserBase.java:635)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserBase.java:576)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._handleUnusualFieldName(ReaderBasedParser.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._parseFieldName(ReaderBasedParser.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:118)
```

and when running the code to deserialise a resource file containing string of this format I get `Exception while deserialising because of hyphen in field names`.

I tried fasterxml ObjectMapper also but it does not work

So how do I debug the string to the map ?

Comment: It's not a valid JSON

Comment: Yes it is not. readValue is only for deserialising valid json ?

Comment: So how do I do i deserialise it ?

Comment: Also fasterxml does not have an ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES configuration just like codehaus.json

Comment: Here is a question on similar problem witht ObjectMapper  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815231/allow-unquoted-field-names-in-jackon-json-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we deserialise the above String

```
try {    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("resourceFile");
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    TypeReference<HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>>() {};
    cmMappings = mapper.readValue(resource.getInputStream(), typeRef);
} catch (Exception ex) {
   // log error    
}
```