# JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote

Tags: java, serialization, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to integrate Spring Cloud streams and publishing a custom Java Object across services with RabbitMQ as broker. The object I am publishing looks like:

```
public class AppMessageEnvelope implements Serializable {
  ...
  private Object messageBody;
  private Date sentAt = new Date();
  ...

  // setters and getters
}
```

This is just a wrapper object and the original object is put in `messageBody`. The object I am putting in `messageBody` looks like:

```
public class Job {
    ...
    private String message;
    private Map<MyEnum, String> myMap;
    ...
}
```

Note that both `AppMessageEnvelope` and `Job` are in a different **model** project which is imported as a Maven dependency in the publisher and subscriber Spring Boot projects, so models are exactly the same.

In producer, I publish the object as:

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class JobDistributor {

    private final Source jobQueue;

    @Autowired
    public JobDistributor(Source jobQueue) {
        this.jobQueue = jobQueue;
    }

    public AppMessageEnvelope publishJob(AppMessageEnvelope message) {
        LOG.info("Sending message: {}.", message);
        jobQueue.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
        return message;
    }
}
```

In consumer, I get the message as:

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class JobConsumer {

    private final JobManager jobManager;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public JobConsumer(
            JobManager jobManager, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.jobManager = jobManager;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
    public void processData(AppMessageEnvelope messageEnvelope) {
        LOG.info("Envelope received: {}.", messageEnvelope);

        try {
            TypeReference<Job> mapType = new TypeReference<Job>() {};
            Job job = objectMapper.readValue(messageEnvelope.getMessageBody().toString(), mapType);
            jobManager.processRequest(job);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Couldn't convert to correct object for processing: {}.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use `TypeReference` to convert the internal object into a correct object but I get an error as:

```
JobConsumer - Couldn't convert to correct object for processing: {}.
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
    at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 3]
```

Before the message is converted, I log it:

```
JobConsumer - Envelope received: AppMessageEnvelope{..., messageBody={id=5bf3a7302dbe9c7cf9927c60, jobId=8c0bfcb0b21248e694b5cd52337a1f9e, submittedAt=2018-11-20T06:18:24+0000, lastUpdatedOn=null, message=null, ..., fileContentMap={FILE_BYTES=JVBERi0xLjUKJb/3ov}}, sentAt=Tue Nov 20 11:48:24 IST 2018}
```

I tried configuring `ObjectMapper` as:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    factory.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES);
    return new ObjectMapper(factory);
}
```

I tried enabling unquoting fields with this too:

```
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

I tried solutions provided by [this blog](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-was-expecting-double-quote-to-start-field-name/) and some similar SO problem but nothing solved. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please try this 

return new ObjectMapper().configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);

Comment: Sorry I missed that I tried this as well. Let me add this to the OP.

Comment: Can you please check your JSON is vaild. Please also have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815231/allow-unquoted-field-names-in-jackon-json-library

Comment: Yes it is. I mean publisher publishes it as a POJO so it is internally converted into JSON and consumer accepts the object as `AppMessageEnvelope` and no problem happens there. The problem is when it tries to convert internal object.

Comment: What is printed when you print `messageEnvelope.getMessageBody().toString()` and `messageEnvelope.getMessageBody().getClass()`?

Comment: I actually have few questions. 
1. Why do you have a custom message structure (`AppMessageEnvelope -> Job`) when Spring Message gives you everything you need? I am actually having a hard time understanding what the actual JSON for your object looks like given it's complexity which I don't think is justified. Perhaps you can post it as suggested by @JBNizer. 
2. Why do you explicitly send message to Source.OUTPUT and then returning AppMessageEnvelope? Do you realize that you effectively sending two messages? You don't need to interact with Source in any explicit way.

Comment: As already suggested, the issue seems to be with `messageEnvelope.getMessageBody().toString()` which you are assuming will give a JSON string. (Error also points out the same, i.e. JSON property not starting with ") Can you print this value and validate the same.
Also, you can use ObjectMapper to get a JSON string from `messageEnvelope.getMessageBody()` and then map it to the desired pojo.

Answer (score 2):

Use below json conversion to convert JSON to Model / Entity

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Job job = objectMapper.convertValue(messageEnvelope.getMessageBody().toString(), Job.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be funny error please copy your json and past into online json [formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).
if the validation wrong please rewrite the json manually or encode it.

Error cause: character encoding issue at time of copy from various sources

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem:
Job job = objectMapper.readValue(messageEnvelope.getMessageBody().toString(), mapType);
Just like this:
Job job = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(messageEnvelope.getMessageBody()), mapType);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).